# SQL synchronize between Servers only Columns/Fields without data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, synchronization, sql-server-2014

i have 2 Microsoft SQL Servers, lets call them A and B.

Server A and B starts with all the same tables , with same tablenames and and, but now Server B should have different data (rows).

So if i made many changes to the table columns to Server A (Which should be my Main), like i add the column Birthday to table MyUsers it should only add the column Birthday to Server B on table MyUsers(Without the date/filled cells (rows)).

Is there a easy way to do this? (The synchronize should only happens one time each day or manually )

Comment: You should create the change as an alter script and run it on both

Comment: You are trying to code data replication? Looks pretty similar to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105965/syncing-two-databases-in-sql-server

Comment: @bradbury9 i only want the headers not the filled cells, because i develop a app which is for 2 companys with the same tables but filled which different data which are not the same

Comment: @mjwills i am not sure what you mean by nullable column, i only want if add like varchar column that its get added to the other server too

Comment: @SteveHarris is there a way to it automatically ? like from all tables to another server without knowing the changes?

Comment: There's a bunch of options here... log shipping, AlwaysOn AG, mirroring, etc... when a change is made to A, the same change is made on B. First step is to take a backup on A (the primary) and restore to (B) and then set up one of the many options.

Comment: @scsimon i do not want overwrite anything of the content, only if column gets delted on a the cells of b are lost then, i only want to transfer the columns without any filled data

Comment: Can't envision why...but this sounds like you are trying to set up a disaster recovery. So if something ets deleted from A, you want to copy it back from B. This is fixing an "oops" query. This is where transaction log backups help meet RPO and RTO in a DR environment.

Comment: @scsimon I have two companys with the same program, which uses at moment only 1 sql server, but if i log in into the secound company there should be all set up only from the columns (because the secound company has different customers, bills and and). And i make only changes on the table on the Server A , and if i add columns to it should be also added to server B but without overwriting any content (except by deleting a column). It's like the Alter Script but more automatic over night once, without the sql client who made the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Create a SQL Server Visual Studio Database Project, then create Publish Profiles two both your servers. When you manually publish to Server A, you can then also publish to Server B. Just google the terminology, Database Project, and Publish Profile